# Wake up Windows Azure worker role

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

What is the best way to handle 'urgent' messages in a Windows Azure Worker role?

I have a worker role that starts, does an infinite while(true) loop and in this loop:

1. reads to see if the queue has messages
2. processes them and deletes them
3. if there are no more messages in goes to sleep with Thread.Sleep(interval) for smaller intervals (10s) at first and progressively increases the sleep interval up to 2 minutes
4. if a message appears in the queue it resets the sleep interval to 0s and goes back to step one

The problem is that if the worker is sleeping for 2 minutes and a message appears in the queue  I would like to wake up the worker and not wait for the remaining time.

Is there any way to get the worker role's instance and tell it to wake up? 
I thought about writing something in the database, but then I have the same problem, even if I have a role that does this, how would I go about waking up the other worker role that is already sleeping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the downsides of using Windows Azure Storage Queues. You have to make a choice between cost and latency. If you want to optimize costs you'll implement a backoff policy (like you did) but this means this will have an impact on when your message will be processed (increased latency).

In your case it might be interesting to evaluate Windows Azure Service Bus Queues (read about the differences [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh767287.aspx)). The advantage of using Service Bus Queues is that it supports long-polling, meaning it will keep a connection to the server until a message arrives (or the timeout elapsed).

Here is some example code you would typically write (you will still need to manage exceptions etc...):

```
QueueClient queueClient = factory.CreateQueueClient("myqueue");
while (true)
{
    BrokeredMessage msg = queueClient.Receive(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(45));
    if (msg != null)
    {
        var request = msg.GetBody<CreateOrderMessage>();
        // Do something
        msg.Complete();
    }
}
```

Here are a few good resources that will get you started:

- http://www.cloudcasts.net/devguide/Default.aspx?id=12042
- http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/08/how-to-simplify-scale-inter-role-communication-using-windows-azure-service-bus/
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh697709.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Just sleep for less time. Why are you sleeping for two minutes instead of, say, just one second? Polling a queue once per second from one instance will cost about $0.25 per month in transactions.